# Como usar C# Windows Forms com Firebird e Orientação a Objetos?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, visual-studio-2013, firebird

Recentemente aprendi um pouco de orientação a objetos e *c#*. Porém estou tentando criar uma aplicação que seja desenvolvida em c# *windows* *forms*, com banco de dados *firebird* e orientada a objetos. Mas qual a maneira correta de se fazer isso? Como eu conecto meu banco a minha aplicação e como faço para que ele interaja com a interface do visual studio? Também já vi que é possível usar `App.Config` como no *sql*, mas como faço isso?

---

Por exemplo, atualmente eu tenho o repostório de uma classe e dentro dele crio eventos como adicionar, alterar e etc, geralmente eu faço assim:

```
public void Adicionar(Pais pais)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO PAIS (PAINOME) VALUES('" + pais.PaiNome+ ")";

    Conexao.Active(true);
    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(sql, Conexao.fbCnn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Conexao.Active(false);
}
```

Dessa maneira toda vez que faço alguma alteração nas classes tenho que mudar em todos os repositórios, por exemplo, se eu adiciono um novo campo ao país eu teria que alterar em todas as strings sql adicionando o novo campo. Essa é a maneira correta de se fazer? Eu consigo deixar isso mais automático ou não?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Legal seu interesse pela programação.

Porém, minha dica é: tente fazer as coisas um passo por vez. Aprenda a fazer a conexão através do C#, depois aprenda a usar Windows Forms, depois tente fazer a conexão com Firebird.

Entendo que a vontade de aprender e fazer algo só seu é grande. Mas as coisas acontecem em sequência.

Segue abaixo alguns tutoriais em português, nada difícil de encontrar no Google, e nada menos do que você encontrará por aqui, sendo sua pergunta tão genérica.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/conectando-em-uma-base-de-dados-firebird-com-c/11938

http://www.macoratti.net/08/09/c_fbd1.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014097/how-to-connect-and-use-firebird-db-embedded-server-with-visual-c-sharp-2010

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas e pela ajuda!

Comment: Da um up aí então, se você considerou como resposta ;)

Comment: Sou novo aqui e nem manjo muito! Foi mal.

Comment: É só clicar no icone ao lado da minha resposta, dizendo que é a resposta certa. Abraço